# Pass Data between Windows

Tags: tkinter, toplevel

I am new in this forum and have a question that deals with me for days.
For exercise purposes, I created two Windows, the second Windows is called as module "textbetrachter" from first Window (MainWindow).
As far as all, the second window is called via a key combination "Self.Bind ("  ", Self.win2)" and that works as well as I said.

My question is: How can I pass the variable "liste" (values) on the 2nd Window (Toplevel), to continue working there. Exactly at this point I just make a programming error.
The error message is:

Print (self.win.list)
AttributeError: 'Toplevel' Object Has No Attributes 'List'

Here's the program I made by me:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import textbetrachter

class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.title("Lektion: Frame-Widget")

        frame_01 = tk.Frame(self, bg="red", width=600, height=200)
        frame_01.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="w")

        frame_01a = tk.LabelFrame(frame_01, text="Rahmen 1:", bg="gray", width=330, height=190)
        frame_01a.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=5, pady=5)

        frame_01b = tk.LabelFrame(frame_01, text="Rahmen 2:", bg="lightgray", width=330, height=190)
        frame_01b.grid(column=2, row=0, padx=(0,5), pady=5)

        self.liste  = frame_01.config()

        self.bind("<Control-s>",self.win2)

    def win2(self, event):
        self.mein_textbetrachter = textbetrachter.Textbetrachter()
        #self.mein_textbetrachter.win.liste
        self.mein_textbetrachter.win.mainloop()


root = MainWindow()
root.mainloop()
```

And this is the module "textbetrachter" (saved as textbetrachter.py):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Textbetrachter():
    def __init__(self):
        self.win = tk.Toplevel()
        self.win.title("Textbetrachter")
        self.win.resizable(False, False)

        frame_02 = tk.Frame(self.win, bg="green")
        frame_02.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=5, pady=5)

        texteditor = tk.Text(frame_02, bg="lightyellow", height=20)
        texteditor.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=5, pady=5)

        text_scroller = tk.Scrollbar(frame_02, orient="vertical", command=texteditor.yview)
        text_scroller.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky="ns")


        print(self.win.liste)

        for item in self.win.liste.config():
               texteditor.insert(tk.INSERT, (item, ":", self.win.liste[item], "\n"))
```

So here in the second window. I would like to continue working with the variables "liste", but unfortunately that does not work. I would be very happy if someone could help me here.

Greetings
SC19

Comment: Quick solution: in the method win2 replace the out comment line with `setattr(self.mein_textbetrachter.win, "liste",self.liste)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the list to the second window.

```py
class Textbetrachter():
    def __init__(self, liste):
        self.liste = liste
        ...

class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    ...
    def win2(self, event):
        self.mein_textbetrachter = textbetrachter.Textbetrachter(self.liste)
        ...
```

If there's more than one variable you need to share, then pass the instance of  `MainWindow` instead:

```py
class Textbetrachter():
    def __init__(self, mainwindow):
        self.mainwindow = mainwindow
        ...
        print(self.mainwindow.liste)

class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    ...
    def win2(self, event):
        self.mein_textbetrachter = textbetrachter.Textbetrachter(self)
        ...
```

Also, you shouldn't call `mainloop` in `MainWindow`. Your program only needs a single event loop.

Comment: For Python it seems no difference in both variants I can pass several variables. And I can call the parameter "mainwindow" also "xyz" It works anyway. Can someone explain why that's the way it is?

Comment: @sc19: You are correct there's little difference between the variants. The point is, if an object needs to reference something in another object, it needs a reference to that object or an attribute of that object. And yes, you can name the parameter anything in the other class. Names are irrelevant, what's important is what the variable refers to.